# Looking for encryption method

Tags: php, encryption

I have a blackbox system whose code is hidden from the end user. That's the intent anyway, I know some may break into it, but generally it's closed.

It's running on PHP, and I need to export a database for backup purposes. This database contains some data I don't want the user to tamper with, so the idea is obvious - encrypt the data file.

I can use RSA, but I'm not sure if it's the best, considering both private and public keys would be embedded in the code. I can also password-protect a zip containing the data file. There's maybe other methods I'm unaware of.

Here's a silly ASCII art diagram of what I want

```
 /*

+----------black-box system-----------+
|                                     |
|   +----------+      ??????????????  |  +-------------+
|   | SQL DUMP | ===> ? ENCRYPTION ? ==> # BACKUP FILE #
|   +----------+      ??????????????  |  +-------------+
|                                     |         v
|   +----------+      ??????????????  |  +-------------+
|   | SQL DUMP | <=== ? DECRYPTION ? <== # BACKUP FILE #
|   +----------+      ??????????????  |  +-------------+
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+

*/
```

The file should be readable by the app again, for "restore from backup" functionality.

Please, suggest how to protect the file. Thanks.

Comment: Who must have the ability to decrypt the data so that it is usable?

Comment: See the updated diagram ;) Basically the system itself should be able to decrypt the file, protecting it from the user's attempt at messing it up. Also, the support service may have the ability to decrypt the file, but that's not essential.

Comment: openssl can be used to encrypt files.  Just put it into your backup script.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16056298/156671

Comment: Alright, well, you haven't really given us any criteria for selecting an encryption algorithm.  Any decent one should satisfy your requirement, however.  You don't need public keys for this; just use symmetric encryption.

Comment: Well that's true, I just need some idea what to try. It must be available in PHP. What'd you suggest?

Comment: Your code isn't hidden from anyone. [There is no such thing in security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). Even if it may turn out to be true, it's a dangerous mindset because it's tempting to put secrets in the code (when the only secret should be in a key, which can easily be replaced if anything is leaked).

Comment: I suggest you [make use of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+encrypting+data).

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's exactly why I asked, thanks for useful suggestion.

Comment: *"This database contains some data I don't want the user to __tamper__ with, so the idea is obvious - encrypt the data file"*, this sounds like you can use message authentication (MAC) instead of encryption, that is you don't care if people can read the data.  Encryption doesn't mean that you can't tamper with data, it means you can't read it.  If I flip some bits in the encryption data, and try to decrypt, it will likely decrypt but be incorrect.

Comment: Wtf why is this "offtopic"? Specifically to avoid this, I didn't ask on StackOverflow. This site is supposed to allow this kind of questions.

Comment: This is doable if you, like you said, trust the black box: Create a hash of the backup. Store it somewhere, maybe in a file. Store all previous hashes also, so keep a history of them. Then when black box is asked to import a file just hash the file and see if you know it. If you don't know it don't load it. A hash like md5 will do sufficiently here. Also a MAC as noted will work. You just don't want to see the file get out and changed. Encryption is an option here (if you don't want them to able to read) but it might also give big issues because you cannot bypass that if well implemented.

Comment: Yeah I've ended up with some symmetric cipher using mcrypt, since the main goal is to avoid users from reading and editing the file. Once they breach the system and have access to the source code, thus also the key, they already have full control and I don't need to worry about something like this, which they can easily bypass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is casual security, so you might as well just flip a coin. Not to be sarcastic, but if you store your keys in code and are sharing the key across all users of your app, and your goal is just to obscure the data from casual tampering, then it really doesn't matter. Pick a symmetric cipher (AES-128 block cipher for example) and be done. It is commonly supported and also fast on modern hardware.

Just make sure not to market the feature as "secure". It is casual anti-tampering, but not secure.

Comment: Three nitpicks: (1) AES is not a stream cipher (2) AES-256 has no practical advantage over AES-128. 128 bit is safe against brute force as long as computers are made out of matter and occupy spacetime, CTCs excluded. (3) AES-256's key schedule may be *weaker*, it's been exploited for related-key attacks and attacks only ever get better.

Comment: Thanks, yes I wrote RC4 orginally, then edited before submitting and failed to revise the sentence.

Comment: WRT the rest, I'm aware of those things. As I said in the answer, it seems the OP is after casual anti-tampering. Though you have a point, AES-128 is faster by a good margin, so maybe a better "choice"